# A Logic gate I cant quite get a handle on

Tags: logic

**Hi,**
Can anyone give me the logic gate that outputs 0 with 1 1, Outputs 1 with 0 1, outputs 0 with 1 0 and outputs 1 with 0 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0|0->1

0|1->1

1|0->0

1|1->0

Is seems that you need to check only one input. The other one is not used. Why then you use two inputs instead of one?

Simple function for your case in c++:

```
bool MyFunction(bool a, bool b) {
    return !a;
}
```

That code does what you want but variable 'b' is useless and you should rethink your problem.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer. It was a poor question asked in the wrong place. By the time I'd received your answer I'd realized the answer, less of a coding problem and more of an electrician problem